# Generate swagger yaml model definitions from java pojo

Tags: java, json, maven, yaml, swagger

I have multiple java classes, But there will be a single class which will reference of all classes (like a request that has all other objects reference). I want to generate swagger yaml documentation for the same automatically but some maven plugin or some utility. Here is the example .

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RequestHolder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8687560483549617990L;

    private String payload;
    private String id;
    private String tenant;

// setter and getter
}

corresponding swagger definition (manually written)

    definitions:
      RequestHolder:
          type: "object"
          required:
          - "trackingIdentifier"
          - "payload"
          - "tenant"
          properties:
            id:
              type: "string"
            payload:
              type: "string"
            tenant:
              type: "string"
```

I searched a bit nothing seems to be existing for this requirement. I have complex relations and list that will take a lot of time to manually do this stuff. Any plugin or utility will be quiet helpful. or even some direction is for research is also welcome.